# Ruby on rails form_tag - sending model parameters to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Controller: `@micropost = Micropost.new(params[:micropost])`

But this form_tag is sending me `params[:content]` instead of `params[:micropost][:content]`

```
<%= form_tag( {:controller => :microposts, :action => :create}, :remote => true) do %>

    <%= text_area_tag :content, "", :size=> "20x2" %>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <%= submit_tag "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

server:

```
Processing by MicropostsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "content"=>"sdfsdf", "commit"=>"submit"}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to do either of the following

```
<%= text_area_tag "micropost[content]", "", :size=> "20x2" %>
```

OR

```
<%= form_for :micropost, :url=>{ :controller => :microposts, :action => :create}, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, "", :size=> "20x2" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to avoid mixing `form_for` and `input_tag`.

When you declare a `form_for @an_object do |form|`, the best practice is to use `form.text_area :content` when `:content` is an attribute of your `@an_object`.

In this case, you can also write: `text_area_tag "an_object[content]"`, but it's a little more dirty.